# System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object - VF Page Error

Tags: null-pointer

I am getting the error on click of button in VF Page. 
In the controller , we are getting data from one object and grouping and performing some arithmetic operations and creating records.

In the debug log , we can see that data is being queried from the source object. 
Number of rows in debug log is equal to rows in developer console query . Hence , data is there.

Still why this error ?

Class.ABCDController.Method1: line 1001, column 1

Class.ABCDController.Method2: line 2002, column 1

The line number mentioned are where there is data present. Rest all loops don't have data at all.

line 2002- Method2(map1, map2);---> These maps are of object types A and B , and currently donot have data. Records weren't formed . If there was no error for this VF , records would have been formed.

A feedback given was - Data is only queried , not updated .Hence the error . -- Not sure what that means .

Please suggest.

Comment: unless you share you code, its tough to answer where the issue is and how to get thru that..

Comment: Did you query the fields that you are trying to access?
Are you iterating over the list size properly?

Comment: @GrayB Yes  , querying the correct fields.  This is working in other orgs and was working in production couple of days back as well .

Comment: @VamsiKrishna Code is pretty huge . Is there anything in particular that I need to check?

Comment: @Vanilla_Sky Run a debug log and you should be able to get a better idea of where the actual error is.  Look for the error message and it should give you some line numbers nearby.